# How do i join the two records and return the table data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, koala, koala-gem

I'm using the gem Koala to get facebook friends.

How to relate these results to the users of the database ?

code

```
facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:facebook_access_token])
friends = facebook.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

return

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mick Fanning",
    "id": "9523891481361"
  },
  {
    "name": "Gabriel Medina",
    "id": "9523891483211"
  }
]
```

Idea:

```
join = friends.map {|u| {
  :user => user = User.where(provider_uid: u['id']).first,
  :provider_uid => u['id'],
  :name => u['name']
}}
```

This will generate lots of queries...

How do i join the two records and return the table data?

Comment: Tell me your requirement in _pain_ english, and allow me to give you a code back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, it seems I got your need. Do the query first.

```
 users = User.where(provider_uid: friends.map { |h| h['id'] })
 users.map do |u|
   {
       :user => u,
       :provider_uid => u.id,
       :name => friends.find { |f| f['id'] == u.id }['name']
   }
 end
```